# Regex to match specific number format

Tags: regex

I am having trouble figuring out how to write a regex to match a number (technically a string) with the following rules:

- all numeric
- must be exactly 11 digits
- it must start with at least 2 zeros
- it may not start with more than 4 zeros

I can use `\d{11}` to match for the exactly 11 digits, and `^0{2,4]` to match the leading zeros part, but I can't figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^00(?!000)\d{9}$
```

It checks for two zeroes and then checks that there are not more than 2 0's following it.
if it is not it checks the other 9 numbers to the end of the string.

This assumes your engine supports lookaheads.

Comment: I included a version without lookarounds which should be faster.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, of course there can be 0's later. Sorry about that

Comment: @RobinGertenbach: Your first method is right. Second method is incorrect as it fails for `00010000111` i.e `0` at 5th place.

Comment: Second one (edit) is ... yeah, wrong. If you want to avoid lookarounds (why would you? They're fine..) you can use `^00([1-9]\d{2}|0[1-9]\d|00[1-9])\d{6}$`, but I don't regard that as better...

Comment: I was also wondering if it could be done (efficiently) without lookaheads. An explicit OR group for `0/not-0` and `not-0` maybe? @Wrikken: OP does not mention a specific language. Not all languages support lookarounds.

Comment: Ah, true that, solution is to use a better language :P (but yeah, you've got a point there).

Comment: It shouldn't be too complex to avoid the lookahead but the expression will be longer. Since OP didn't state the engine I wasn't sure if it supports that. I usually work in environments where I have to make do without lookarounds.